# Are there any ways to include conditional statements in MATCH WHERE queries for PostgreSQL running AGE?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I am trying to match nodes `a` where the sizes for `a.category` are less than or equal to 9. I would like to place a condition for `a.category` sizes that are exactly the size of 9, that only the nodes with their first character being 'c' will be matched. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('Graph', $$
    MATCH (a)
    WHERE size(a.category <= 9) AND
        substring(a.category, 0, 1)) = 'c' ONLY IF (size(a.category) = 9)
    RETURN a.name
$$) AS (name agtype);
```

If the `IF` statement does not exist or will not work in this circumstance, are there any ways to achieve the same result with a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you described can be achieved by the following query

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('Graph', $$
MATCH(a)
WHERE (size(a.category) < 9) OR (size(a.category) = 9 AND 
substring(a.category, 0,1) = 'c') 
RETURN a.name $$) AS (name agtype);
```

You can split the logic as first matching if the size of category is 9 OR (size is 9 AND category starts with letter c).

Answer (score 0):

use `AND` instead of `IF`

like this

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('Graph', $$
    MATCH (a)
    WHERE size(a.category <= 9) AND (size(a.category) = 9) AND substring(a.category, 0, 1)) = 'c'
    RETURN a.name
$$) AS (name agtype);
```

Comment: Using `WHERE size(a.category <= 9) AND size(a.category) = 9` ultimately results in just `WHERE (size(a.category) = 9)`, and the sizes less than 9 will not be matched in the end.